# Magento Collections PHP

Tags: php, collection

I am new to using magento collections and am receiving exhausted memory fatal errors. I just want to double check that my collection is pulling what i think it is.

I believe this is grabbing all products including the attribute 'part_num'. It then filters out all products with part_num == '' (blank) or ' ' (space).

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

$collection->addAttributeToSelect('part_num'); 

$collection->addAttributeToFilter(array(
array('attribute'=>'part_num','neg'=>''),
));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(array(
array('attribute'=>'part_num','neg'=>' '),
));
```

This would leave me with all products that have some data in the part_num attribute. Is this correct?

Comment: Use Mage::log((string) $collection->getSelect()); Then view the log and see that SQL you're getting. Try the SQL in your client and it may help you see if there is a huge payload coming back - whether it is more than you want.

Comment: Thanks that is a nifty trick! Its exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

This looks about right, however your filter is wrong. `neg` should be `neq`.

So:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

$collection->addAttributeToSelect('part_num'); 

$collection->addAttributeToFilter('part_num',array('neq'=>''));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('part_num',array('neq'=>' '));
```